# Flipped Images for SharePoint 2013

Tags: windows10

Some of the images that we upload to SharePoint 2013 look fine on the Windows 10 Photo viewer, but display upside down once uploaded to the website. Windows 7 photo editor never caused any issues. Is there a setting that I need to change in SharePoint to display images the way they show on the computer via photo viewer?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue and here is a work around to overcome this issue :

1. First I uploaded a picture from my computer to the SharePoint site.
   It uploaded fine.
2. Then I uploaded an image sent by client to the SharePoint and
   noticed it was upside down (see image above), even though it was
   right side up when I opened the same saved image from my computer.
3. I uploaded the second and third picture and they behaved the same
   way. They were right side up when opened from the computer but as
   soon as they were uploaded to SharePoint they turned upside down.
4. I then saved the first upside down picture in SharePoint to my
   desktop. I figured I will work with one image at a time and see what
   happens.
5. I deleted the first image from SharePoint after I saved it to my
   desktop.
6. I opened the newly saved picture on my desktop and opened it in
   Windows Picture Viewer. It was upside down just the way it looked in
   SharePoint. Keep in mind that the picture originally was fine and
   was right side up when the client sent it to us. It only got flipped
   upside down when it was uploaded to SharePoint.
7. I flipped the picture upside down so it looked the way it was
   supposed to look (i.e. right side up). By the way, opening it in
   Microsoft Paint and flipping it upside down also yielded the same
   results.
8. I then uploaded this picture to the SharePoint site again and it
   fortunately was right side up. Whew!
9. I repeated these steps for the other two pictures and it worked.
   They were finally uploaded to the SharePoint and displayed right
   side up as shown below.

[SharePoint image turn upside down](https://www.zubairalexander.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/RightSideUp.png)

Source of above workaround steps :

[Images Turn Upside Down When Uploaded To SharePoint 2013](https://www.zubairalexander.com/blog/images-turn-upside-down-when-uploaded-to-sharepoint-2013/)